# Return MongoDB query result to shell

Tags: mongodb, shell

I use the mongoimport command in shell to load a json file in MongoDB.

```
mongoimport \
    --host ${MONGO_HOST}:${MONGO_PORT} \
    --db ${MONGO_DB} \
    --type json \
    --collection ${COLLECTION} \
    --file ${DATA_IN_PATH}/${FILENAME}.json \
    --upsert \
    --upsertFields ${UPSERT_FIELDS}
```

I would like to count the number of documents in my collection, before and after the load and get it in a shell variable

I tried Using the --eval command and put the result into a variable:

```
CollCount=$(mongo \
    ${MONGO_HOST}:${MONGO_PORT}/${MONGO_DB} \
    --eval "db.getCollection('${COLLECTION}').count({})")
```

but my var CollCount contains:

> MongoDB shell version: 2.6.9 connecting to: localhost:27017/mydb 12236

(The value  12236 is correct.)

Is it a better way to do this?

Comment: You can use `db.collection.stats()` as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/)

Comment: I think you are just missing `--quiet` on the `mongo` shell command line (which should suppress the version & connection message).

Comment: @Stennie: That works with the --quiet